# Storing MySQL password as hash

Tags: c#, mysql, database, security

I know this has been asked many times before, but I can't find the answer I am looking for:

I have a C# application that connects to a MySQL database, currently the username, password and database name are stored in plain text in a .cnf file, which is very insecure.

Is it possible to store the database's password as a hash in the config and pass that instead of the a plain string?  This would at least be a bit more secure.

Thanks you.

Comment: Try using Enterprise Library.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt password in App.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522879/encrypt-password-in-app-config)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely connect to mySQL database in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343385/safely-connect-to-mysql-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

security through obscurity will not work. furthermore, storing as a hash won't work as hashes can't be decrypted and are only used for comparison.

Look here for more information: [Safely connect to mySQL database in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343385/safely-connect-to-mysql-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new DLL file which just store the credentials. But to change it you will should to compile new version of DLL